# opening standard stream in google-chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I have a program that creates a html file as standard output.  To view it in vim I just need to:

```
$ foo2html foo | vim -
```

vim will be launched with stdin read-in for viewing.  Once I close vim the command will return.

Is there some combination of command-line switches that will make google-chrome do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think so. But you can do it via a temporary file instead:

```
TEMPFILE=`tempfile` && foo2html foo > $TEMPFILE && google-chrome $TEMPFILE
```

Answer (score 10):

Just use [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
# google-chrome
echo '<h1>hello</h1>' | google-chrome "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0)"

# firefox (it will not automatic open since version 89, you must go to url and press enter)
echo '<h1>hello</h1>' | firefox "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0)"

# chromium
echo '<h1>hello</h1>' | chromium "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0)"

# opera
echo '<h1>hello</h1>' | opera "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0)"

# Default browser (in debian systems)
echo '<h1>hello</h1>' | x-www-browser "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0)"
```

The command base64 is available from coreutils on debian like systems

```
sudo apt-get install coreutils
```

If you not have coreutils installed or you cannot install new packages, you could use the python module base64 (virtually any distro has python)

```
echo '<h1>hello</h1>' | google-chrome "data:text/html;base64,$(python -mbase64)"
```

Comment: Is the `<&0` necessary? It seems it can be omitted, but maybe there are some situtations in which it's required?

Comment: @k314159 `<&0` is not necessary