# Chromium headless PDF generation (in Java) using String instead of temp file/page

Tags: java, string, memory, pdf-generation, chromium

We currently use the PhantomJS executable for two things in our Java project:

1. Create a PDF file from a given `String html` we get from our database (for which we write the String to a temp file first)
2. Create a screenshot of a given Widget-Object (for which we have an open HTML page on the front-end)

Since PhantomJS hasn't been updated for a few years, I'm about to change it to a headless Chromium method instead, which has the options `--print-to-pdf` and `--screenshot` for options 1 and 2.

Option 2 isn't really relevant since we have a page, but for option 1 it would be nice if we could directly use the chromium command-line with the given String. Right now with PhantomJS, we convert the String to a temp file, and then use the executable to generate the actual PDF output file. I can of course do the same with the headless Chromium executable, but since I'm changing it right now anyway, it would be nice if the 'String to temp HTML file' step wouldn't be necessary for creating the output PDF file, since we already have the page in memory anyway after retrieving it from the database.

From what I've seen, the Chromium executable is usually run for either a HTML file to PDF file:

```
chromium --headless -disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:/path/to/output-file.pdf" C:/path/to/input-file.html
```

Or for a HTML page to PDF file:

```
chromium --headless -disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:/path/to/output-file.pdf" https://www.google.com/
```

I couldn't really find the docs for the `chrome`/`chromium` executable (although I have been able to find [the list of command options in the source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc;bpv=0;bpt=1)), so maybe there are more options besides these two above? (If anyone has a link to the docs, that would be great as well.)
If not, I guess I'll just use a temp file as we did before with PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

The terms 'chrome read stdin' would probably have brought you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045584) explaining how to read from a data url:

```
chrome.exe "data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PHRpdGxlPlRlc3Q8L3RpdGxlPjwvaGVhZD48Ym9keT5ZbzwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+"
```

Reading input from stdin sounds like you would also want to write the output to stdout: 'chrome pdf to stdout'. Which links to someone trying the same thing and running into issues about [not being able to combine --stdout with screenshot or pdf output](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=732052) from 2018.
And (depending on the usecase) even worse, a limitation of the data url's of 2MB.

So if you can't guarantee the input to be less than 2MB you might be better off using files anyway, or check if the limitation has been removed.

Also, given that you specify that option 2 has a solution in serving the page directly, would that not also open up the option to do the same for option 1?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need redundant `-disable-gpu` usure which version it was not needed for Windows, but redundant in https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1161172 (2018), however, you may want to replace with `--print-to-pdf-no-header` to avoid those.

Your using windows as the shell to run Chrome/MSEdge.exe so for that reason there will be a significantly smaller command line ability to CMD pass a variable string.

To pass a base64 for html string as stdin will often be limited by content for similar string length reasons to say 1.5MB (75% of 2MB). Thus in special exceptional cases that may be 4096 pages see https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/Hanoi.htm however the norm is usually **only a few standard html pages**.

PDF file handling requires a file system to generate the pages, thus a file centred approach to store the decimal based file index. So the memory work around is to use a RamDrive/Disk or its Bytes IO equivalent as named FileStream object.

Using PDF data in memory is usually highly disk intensive as the limited resources after contents program processing need to draw on the bus disk cache to augment virtual ram. As a result working in memory can be just as slow if not slower than using cached disk file data.

%Tmp% / %temp% files can usually respond quicker and be very easily overwritten.

There are many other working and non-working switches bandied about the web, but the semi-official list is https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/